# Knowledge and certainty

Tags: epistemology, knowledge

From a French point of view, influenced by Descartes, knowledge is strongly linked to certainty: strictly speaking says Descartes, I cannot know anything unless it is impossible for me to doubt it, that is, unless I am certain about it. In traditional French philosophy, knowledge is defined as " (1) connaissance [hard to translate:  cognizance, acquaintance] (2) certaine"

However, I see that in the English-speaking philosophical world, certainty is so to say absent from discussions regarding language. I cannot see where certainty can be found in the standard definition of knowledge as true justified belief.

How to explain this?

Comment: For Descartes a belief is justified only if it is certain, so that’s where it is found.

Comment: "Justified true belief" is Plato's formula, it is not an English speaking idea, and the certainty is supposed to be in the "justified", since Plato believed that we can achieve absolute justification via anamnesis. Emphasis on certainty is generally typical of epistemological foundationalists, who include Kant and Husserl, among others, so it is not specific to France. It is true that Anglophone philosophy always had a strong empiricist bent, and emphasized fallibility of knowledge, vs French/German rationalism. But I am not sure what would count as "explanation". Traditional practicality?

Comment: Certainty as a psychological state is really no more than presumption. Logically justified certainty is the comprehension that the a conclusion is logically entailed by premises that are necessarily true.

Comment: The most certainly true assertion is "existence exists". Any attempt to prove that existence does not exist would be self-refutational, (because it would form an example of a thing that exists thus a counter-example to the claim that "existence does not exist" ). This makes the assertion that "existence exists" is irrefutable.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I see that in the english speaking philosophical world, certainty is so to say absent from discussions regarding language. I cannot see where certainty can be found in the standard definition of knowledge as true justified belief. How to explain this?

I think that the theory of knowledge as justified true belief is typical of analytical philosophy, which is hegemonic in English-speaking countries, and in particular in the United States.

*Certainty*, however, is a psychological condition and certainty that p doesn't imply p and therefore doesn't imply knowledge that p.

As I understand it, Descartes' idea is that doubt disproves knowledge, an idea he put to very effective use to arrive at the Cogito. However, as a psychological condition, certainty itself seems immune to analysis and therefore of little interest in particular to analytically-minded philosophers.

Is there an overlap?

Certainty applies to beliefs. We have beliefs, and we are certain of some of our beliefs while uncertain of others. Some of the beliefs we are certain of *may be* actual knowledge. Uncertainty, i.e. doubt, disproves knowledge, according to Descartes, but certainty doesn't prove knowledge.

So, there is perhaps an overlap.

Let's assume p is true. Let's assume further that subject A believes that p, and that A is somehow justified in believing that p. The theory of justified true belief says that, under those assumptions, subject A knows that p. However, what if A has some doubts about believing that p. Descartes would say that therefore A doesn't know that p (the slightest doubt is enough to disprove knowledge).

So, here it seems we have a clear contradiction between the two perspectives, one analytical philosophy, the other a typically "continental" philosophy.

The two perspectives are clearly very different but there is nonetheless a striking similarity in the difference...

According to the JTB theory, a justified true belief is *equivalent* to knowledge. However, it is unclear that we could ever *know that we know p* since there is no finite procedure to *decide* that we know that p is indeed true as required.

So, JTB is logically inconclusive since we don't know how to ascertain the truth of at least one of the premises theorised as necessary to the conclusion.

Descartes has also a problem, though. To disprove that you know p, you need to be able to doubt that p. However, *how do you know that you doubt that p*? Descartes doesn't offer any procedure to decide that you know something. His procedure is only effective in *disproving* that you know something. You can prove you don't know that p by being able to doubt that p is true. You cannot prove that you know that p. And, therefore, you cannot prove that it is true that you doubt that p is true.

So, at least as described by Descartes, his view was also logically inconclusive.

Perhaps Bertrand Russell bridged the gap. He made the distinction between propositional knowledge, i.e. subject *A knows that p*, and knowledge by acquaintance where subject *A knows p*.

For example, subject A *knows that* subject B is in pain: This is propositional knowledge. However, subject B is experiencing the pain: Subject B *knows pain*. This is knowledge by acquaintance, although only so *while* pain is being experienced. Knowledge by acquaintance reduces to propositional knowledge *after the event*--There are two terms for knowledge in French: *connaissance*, corresponding to knowledge by acquaintance, and *savoir*, corresponding to propositional knowledge.

Although I dispute the coherence of the theory of justified true belief, nonetheless it seems to me that its object is propositional knowledge, while Descartes' Cogito is typical of knowledge by acquaintance.

And perhaps the twain shall never meet.

Comment: @Speakpigeon.Thanks for this detailed and inspiring analysis!

Comment: "Certainty, however, is a psychological condition and certainty that p doesn't imply p and therefore doesn't imply knowledge that p." Logically justified certainty is not psychological and is always based in semantic tautology.

Comment: @polcott (1) I don't understand the concept of "logically justified certainty" unless it be psychological in nature. Maybe you could give a convincing example. - (2) Semantic tautology, I would assume, requires a lot of psychological huffing and puffing over what logical system is correct. Where's the proof that any system is correct?

Comment: Successor(Successor(Successor(0))) = 3 We know that Successor(Successor(Successor(0))) equals 3 is true on the basis that the symbol: "3" on the RHS is stipulated to correspond to the (Peano axiom) algorithm on the LHS.

Comment: "a tautology is a formula whose negation is unsatisfiable."  A semantic tautology carries this same idea a little further. An expression of language that is necessarily true entirely based on its meaning: "Dogs are not cats" is impossibly false within the conventional meanings of those terms.

Comment: Certainty as a psychological state is really no more than presumption. Logically justified certainty is the comprehension that the a conclusion is logically entailed by premises that are necessarily true.

Comment: The most certainly true assertion is "existence exists". Any attempt to prove that existence does not exist would be self-refutational, (because it would form an example of a thing that exists thus a counter-example to the claim that "existence does not exist" ). This makes the assertion that "existence exists" is irrefutable.

Comment: @polcott 1. I have no idea what "existence exists" could possibly mean, and the reason for that I think it is because it is self-referential, and as such, I would say it is false. - 2. Tautologies are not suppose to even say anything about the world, let alone constituting knowledge of it. So, all we can say is that we know the tautologies, somewhat like we know pain when in pain, but this about our own mind, not knowledge of the world. 3. "Successor" and "logically justified certainty". Same thing. Mathematics isn't about the world. It is about how our mind represents the world.

Comment: "I have no idea what "existence exists" could possibly mean." The abstract object (AKA idea) of {existence} is a member of the set of established ideas. I am creating a brand new idea that I named {semantic  tautology}. A semantic tautology occurs when a new combination of ideas is assigned to a word or phrase making a brand new term. To verify that a semantic tautology is true only requires verifying that this set of ideas has been assigned to this term. That cats are animals is an example of a semantic tautology.

Comment: @polcott "Existence exists" doesn't mean "the idea of existence exist".

Comment: What else could it possibly mean?

Comment: @polcott Existence exists means existence exists. Beyond that, I don't know, it doesn't make sense.But it does not mean that the idea of existence exists. It doesn't even imply existence of the idea. If we are not equivocating on words.

Comment: Of course anyone can disagree with anything. The trick is to have an actual basis for disagreement. You could deny that you yourself exist and never realize that this denial is its own complete refutation. Likewise for the existence of existence.

Comment: @polcott We seem to have run out of things to say.

Comment: So your claim that the term "existence exists" does not apply to the idea of {existence} is baseless?

Comment: You seemed to imply that the term "existence exists" has no meaning entirely on the basis that it is self-referential. I coined the term {pathological self reference} back in 2004  on comp.theory referring to the subset of expressions that are semantically malformed because they are self-referential. This sentence is comprised of words is self-referential and semantically sound.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Could you clarify this in your answer: "You can prove you don't know that p by being able to doubt that p is true." I'm under the impression there is always a doubt to be had by someone as to the said someone believing that something is true because the individual does not have omnipotence to make the said something he or she would believe in to be a fact of reality. Thus, someone always has the *ability* to doubt "p," as I infer. Then relatively, no one ever knows "p." One should always be able to doubt that "p" is true; but your statement in your answer seems to imply otherwise.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Could you clarify the following: "However, what if A has some doubts about believing that p." Did you mean the following, "However, what if A has some doubts about believing that p of which prevent A from believing that p"?

Comment: @Speakpigeon Could you clarify the following: "Descartes would say that therefore A doesn't know that p (the slightest doubt is enough to disprove knowledge)." Did you mean the following, "Descartes would say that therefore A doesn't know that p (the slightest doubt that prevents A from believing that p is enough to prevent A from having knowledge that p)"?

Comment: @polcott "So your claim that the term "existence exists" does not apply to the idea of {existence} is baseless?" The idea of existence exists and this is unproblematic, but "*existence exists*" does not mean "*the idea of existence exists*" just as "*the universe exists*" does not mean "*the idea of the universe exists"*. Not if you speak English. You use a private language and expect other to understand you.

Comment: @polcott "*The most certainly true assertion is "existence exists"*" We are certain that the idea of existence exists whenever we have the idea of existence in mind, and we probably have it ordinarily in mind, but probably not when dreaming for example. To have an idea in mind means that we have knowledge of it by acquaintance, so we know the idea of existence when we have this idea in mind, and to know something by acquaintance means that (outside dreaming and such) we are certain that it exists, which is just a psychological state.

Comment: @polcott "*The most certainly true assertion is "existence exists"*" When we dream, we also know by acquaintance what we are dreaming, but I wouldn't say that we are certain of anything while dreaming. But we don't make assertions when we dream, not even "existence exists".

Comment: @DennisFrancisBlewett "*the individual does not have omnipotence*" Knowledge does not imply omnipotence. It only implies that what you know is as you think of it, which is the case for the current contents of our conscious mind, including what we dream at the moment that we dream it.

Comment: @DennisFrancisBlewett "*Thus, someone always has the ability to doubt "p," as I infer*" I certainly cannot doubt right now that I exist. We can doubt our beliefs about the sensible world precisely because they are beliefs, not knowledge. We cannot doubt what we know, and we know the current contents of our conscious mind, so we cannot doubt that we know the current contents of our conscious mind. We can always claim otherwise, but only if we equivocate on the notion of knowledge.

Comment: @DennisFrancisBlewett 1. "*However, what if A has some doubts about believing that p.*" This means that we can always doubt our beliefs about the sensible world precisely because they are only beliefs. And we only have beliefs about the sensible world, no knowledge.. 1 "*Did you mean the following, "However, what if A has some doubts about believing that p of which prevent A from believing that p"?*" Sorry, I cannot make sense of your interpretation.

Comment: @DennisFrancisBlewett "*One should always be able to doubt that "p" is true*" This is only true if p is a belief, an idea, a statement etc. about the sensible world. We know nothing about the sensible world. Whatever we say or think about it is subject to revision and therefore not knowledge.

Comment: @DennisFrancisBlewett "*(the slightest doubt that prevents A from believing that p is enough to prevent A from having knowledge that p)*" No, this was not what I meant. No belief is knowledge. You can doubt belief, you cannot doubt knowledge. If you doubt something ever so slightly, it is not knowledge. This is why Descartes' extreme doubt works. Extreme doubt is the weakest form of doubt, but it is nonetheless enough, according to Descartes, to dismiss the idea that what we think is knowledge.

Comment: @Speakpigeon It seems that my example was too difficult. I will provide a simpler one. We can know with 100% perfect logically justified certainty all of those things that can be verified as completely true entirely on the basis of the meaning of their words. https://www.britannica.com/topic/tautology For example we can know that {baby kittens} are no type of {ten story office building} on the basis of the semantic properties assigned to these two terms. This remains true even if we are a brain in a vat connected to a computer simulation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat

Comment: @polcott "*We can know with 100% perfect logically justified certainty all of those things*" We know our own logical intuitions. They don't give us knowledge of the real world. 2. "we can know that {baby kittens} are no type of {ten story office building} on the basis of the semantic properties" No. We don't know that there are baby kittens or buildings in the sensible world. We infer that there are from our perception which we don't know that it is true of the real world. Definitions are rules subject to revision, not knowledge of the real world.

Comment: @Speakpigeon The set of (what  at least appears to be) sensory perceptions is  ncessarily correctly placed into their respective categories even none of these apparent sensory perceptions correspond to any actual physical reality and are only computer simulations fed directly to our brain. For example we know that "baby kittens" never have {elevators} because the semantic properties of assigned to "baby kitten" exclude {elevators}. How do we know that 2 + 3 = 5 and not 2 + 3 = {a plate of burned brownies crushed on the floor} ???

Comment: @polcott "*How do we know that 2 + 3 = 5*" We know it because it is an idea in our own mind and this is all we really know. We can make up theories about how and why it came to our mind, and we clearly do, but theories are beliefs subject to revision, not knowledge. We can tell that in our percept of the world two apples and two different apples are four apples, but that does not prove that there are apples in the real world, or two plus two makes four in the real world. We also cannot explain the reality of the model by whatever the model represents.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Ah I see you simply doubt everything whether or not any doubt is justified because this is your {belief system} whether or not your {belief system} corresponds to actual truth is irrelevant to you. I go from the point of view that every expression of language that is stipulated to be true is necessarily true because stipulated truth is the only way that otherwise meaningless finite strings acquire any semantic meaning what-so-ever.

Comment: @polcott "*you doubt everything*" I told you I know my own ideas, so I don't doubt everything. 2. "*corresponds to actual truth is irrelevant to you*" To believe is to believe it is the actual truth. If not it is imagination, not belief. 3. "*because stipulated truth is the only way that otherwise meaningless finite strings acquire any semantic meaning*" We understand each other's statements before any  explicit definition. We develop beliefs about what words mean, and this is enough. Definitions come after the fact. They are just formalisations of what words mean.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Without defintions coming before the fact all spoken and written words remain utterly meaningless gibberish.

Comment: @polcott "*Without defintions coming before the fact all spoken and written words remain utterly meaningless gibberish.*" This is patently false. Children learn to speak well before they could possibly read any definition. Humans could understand each other well before the invention of any writing system.

Comment: @Speakpigeon "Children learn to speak well before" they have any idea what any words mean. Even though every word is utterly meaningless gibberish they can speak fluently by just happening to say (what is utterly meaningless gibberish to themselves) random sounds that seem to outside observers to be relevant to the conversion.

Comment: @polcott Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

A *very rough explanation* is that French philosophy has *historically* been inclined to various forms of rationalism which stress the power of a priori reason to deliver substantive and even fundamental truths about the world. On the model of mathematics, such truths are - or have been widely taken to be - demonstrable, immune from error, and certain - 'certain' in the sense (not psychological but epistemological) of 'certainly true'.

In equally broad terms, the English-speaking tradition has inclined towards empiricism and a reliance on sense-based knowledge, which is clearly liable to error. The senses are untrustworthy if it is certainty that one is seeking.

None of this does justice to the present state of French or of English-speaking philosophy and historically it neglects *finesse*, ignoring innumerable different streams of philosophical thought that have marked both French and English-speaking philosophy. But the broad historical contrast is correct or at least plausible.

Comment: "*French philosophy has historically been inclined to various forms of rationalism which stress the power of a priori reason to deliver substantive and even fundamental truths about the world*" A very strange assertion given that Descartes explained that we can doubt everything about the sensible world. The only knowledge Descartes believed we have is knowledge of our own existence as a thinking thing, hardly anything "***about the world***".

Comment: "*the English-speaking tradition has inclined towards empiricism*" The theory of knowledge as Justified True Belief" is analytical philosophy, which is itself a product of the English-speaking world.

Answer (score -3):

## The only fully justified certainty that could possibly exist would be stipulated relations between ideas.

This most often happens when a new idea is created and this new idea is assigned to a new term. Whenever any new combination of ideas is assigned to a new term this assignment is stipulating the meaning of this new term. This stipulative definition process becomes the ultimate foundational basis of the meaning of this new term.

A stipulative definition is a type of definition in which a new or currently-existing term is given a new specific meaning for the purposes of argument or discussion in a given context. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stipulative_definition

**Semantic Tautology**
A Semantic Tautology occurs whenever any combination of semantic meanings is assigned to a word or phrase. This most often occurs whenever new combinations of ideas are created or discovered and they are assigned to a new term.

The only reason that we know that "3 > 2" is true is that the relation ">" has been stipulated between "3" and "2" when the ordered set of natural numbers has been defined.

If we construe the definitions of the meaning of words as a stipulated relations between words and their meaning then when we assess that an expression of language is true we would only be asking whether or not the relations that comprise it have been stipulated by its words.

Because we can verify that relations between words and ideas have been stipulated in the present moment it seems that none of the skeptical objections to fully justified certainty can be applied to this case.

Even if the entire universe including all of our memories were created just five minutes ago and the only existence of "cats" and "animals" is in our newly created memory of them the relation that: "a cat is an animal" would never-the-less still exist. This also applies to the brain-in-a-vat (Matrix film trilogy) thought experiment.

**Analytic–synthetic distinction**
(1) analytic proposition: a proposition whose truth depends solely on the meaning of its terms
(2) analytic proposition: a proposition that is true (or false) by definition
(3) analytic proposition: a proposition that is made true (or false) solely by the conventions of language --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction

**Münchhausen trilemma**
In epistemology, the Münchhausen trilemma is a thought experiment used to demonstrate the impossibility of proving any truth, even in the fields of logic and mathematics. If it is asked how any given proposition is known to be true, proof may be provided. Yet that same question can be asked of the proof, and any subsequent proof.

The axiomatic argument, which rests on accepted precepts which are merely asserted rather than defended. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma

Comment: What if we create new terms and ideas? Or if old ideas change meaning because new discoverings? Then perhaps the old truths become false...
There is no rest in this world. All  always changing...

Comment: @framontb This is a very important question. It is very likely that errors would be easily introduced as words gradually evolve their meaning over time. The whole purpose of my answer is to show there are are at least some examples of fully justified certainty. The Münchhausen trilemma denies that there are any such examples at all.

Comment: What about [incorrigible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incorrigibility) beliefs, such as certainty regarding what *seems to me* to be the case? (ex: "I am certain that *it seems to me* that I am commenting on your answer", or "I am certain that *I believe* I am commenting on your answer".) These don't seem like tautologies and they could have even been false.

Comment: @AdamSharpe When I am explaining the one way that certainty is fully justified I am sticking with things that are true by definition (See Semantic Tautology above) and those things derived by valid deduction from premises that are guaranteed to be true because they are true by definition.

Comment: @AdamSharpe That "you" are commenting on my answer is a semantic tautology when we leave open the exact definition of the term {you}. You may be a separate individual person, a computer program, or an aspect of my own subconscious mind. All that we really know about "you" is that you are the source of the message within the communication process. 
http://www.liarparadox.org/CommunicationProcess.png